# Kibana Visual: Show visual only when a field. is decreasing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to set up a simple Kibana line chart with these conditions -
I'm trying to set up a Power vs Timestamp chart. In elastic, I have the metrics Current and Voltage. I'll calculate the Power from that. Problem is, I need to show the visual ONLY if the current is decreasing.
So at time t, the current value should be less than the last reported current value.

Cannot figure out how to do this in Lens. If it can't be done in Lens, any help with Vega is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you want a graph that only shows the values of current for when the previous value is greater. This is not doable in lens, but definitely doable in Vega.

Since you haven't provided an example I will just point you in the right direction. You will need a series of transforms to get the data in a plottable form.

- sort the data by timestamp ([collect transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/collect/))
- run a window transform that stores the previous value ([window transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/window/))
- calculate the difference between these values ([formula transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/formula/))
- filter values with a negative/positive difference ([filter transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/filter/))

From here you can build the marks etc. if Vega is new to you I would start by looking at the [Vega Documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega/), [Vega Gallery](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/) and the [Kibana-Vega Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/vega.html) (for data ingest).

Comment: I didn't realize I hadn't replied here. I did end up using Vega and I used runtime-fields to calculate the metrics required. TYSM!